# Multidimensional Arrays in a struct in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to convert the following (shortened for readability) to C# and running into problems

```
#define DISTMAX 10
struct Distort {
  int    a_order;
  double a[DISTMAX][DISTMAX];
};
```

I thought in structs it was a simple case of using "fixed" however I'm still getting problems.

Here's what I've got (With a define higher up the page):

```
const int DISTMAX = 10;
struct Distort
{
        int a_order;
        fixed double a[DISTMAX,DISTMAX];
}
```

The error I get is stimply Syntax error that ] and [ are expected due to what I expect to be a limitation of a single dimension array.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed sized buffers can only be one-dimensional. You'll need to use:

```
unsafe struct Distort
{
     int a_order;
     fixed double a[DISTMAX * DISTMAX];
}
```

and then do appropriate arithmetic to get at individual values.